# Read and Write Timeouts in JSSC

Tags: java, serial-port, blocking, jssc

In SerialPort.java, I would like to know the following on writeBytes and readBytes methods:

- Would those block?
- How to interpret the return --boolean-- code?

Answer (score 3):

For reading (I'm using version 2.8.0) there are also methods like `readBytes(int byteCount, int timeout)` where you can specify a timeout. For reading the better approach might be to register a `SerialPortEventListener`. In fact I have never tried to uses `readBytes` directly outside of it.

The boolean return code must be `true` for the writing methods. The reason for this is the return code coming from the C++ JNI implementation behind. No exception is thrown in the JNI part, better would be also an exception here.

If you look into the Java code of e.g. `writeBytes(byte[] buffer)` only the first line is throwing a `SerialPortException`, the actual transmission is handled with the boolean return code:

```
this.checkPortOpened("writeBytes()");
return this.serialInterface.writeBytes(this.portHandle, buffer);
```

The write part can block, e.g. if the serial port is not responding. I have used a thread to prevent this, something like this:

```
private static class BackgroundWriter implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private SerialPort serialPort;

    private String atCommand;

    public BackgroundWriter(SerialPort serialPort, String atCommand) {
        this.serialPort = serialPort;
        this.atCommand = atCommand;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {
        // add carriage return
        boolean success = serialPort.writeString(atCommand+"\r");
        return success;
    }
}
```

and later call it with a timeout:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Boolean> writeResult = executorService.submit(new BackgroundWriter(serialPort, atCommand));
boolean success;
try {
    success = writeResult.get(writeTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (serialPort != null && serialPort.isOpened()) {
        try {
            serialPort.closePort();
        } catch (SerialPortException e2) {
            LOGGER.warn("Could not close serial port after timeout.", e2);
        }
    }
    throw new IOException("Could not write to serial port due to timeout.", e);
}
if (!success) {
    throw new IOException("Could not write to serial port [" + serialPort.getPortName() + "]");
}
```

Comment: I get a whole bunch of Background Writer threads left behind with this approach - one for every attempt at writing to the serial port with nothing attached. Is there a nice way of interrupting them?

Comment: The `ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();` should be only called once globally somewhere. My expectation would be then that only single thread is executed and all submitted `BackgroundWriter` are garbage collected later if the JVM needs memory. Otherwise there is something hanging a a not removed reference preventing this.